# Troubleshooting Gradle Performance Issue

Tags: performance, gradle, junit

Recently our build times have been fluxuating wildly. Our baseline was between 1-2mins, but now it is sometimes taking up to 20 mins. I have been trying to track down the cause, but am having some trouble. It feels like the changes that trigger fluxuation in the build time are completely arbitrary, or at least I can not find the underlying connection between them.

Here is what the current build time looks like:
[image]

Now this obviously looks like the issue lies in Task Execution time, so lets look at that in more detail:
[image]

This indicates that the test task for the umlgen-transformer project is the culprit. The only difference between this project and the one that built in ~1min, is one tiny xml file. That xml file is read in by each of the unit tests as input. Here is what a typical test looks like:

```
@Test
def void testComponentNamesUpdated() {
     loadModel("/testData/ProducerConsumer.uml")

     val trafo = new ComponentTransformation

     trafo.execute(model)

     val componentNames = model.allOwnedElements.filter(Component).map[name]

     assertThat(componentNames).contains(#{"ProducerComponent", "ConsumerComponent"})
 }
```

(the .uml file is just a UML model stored as xml). There are several reasons why I don't think this is the underlying cause of our increases in build times: 1) the xml file is incredily small, ~200kb 2) the behavior in the unit tests is extremly  simple and executes quite fast 3) when the unit tests are run through eclipse they execute in seconds 4) the build times of unrelated aspects, such as the time to compile kotlin code, have also seen a significant increase 5) this is not the only project we are having this issue with.

What I have tried:

- Setting org.gradle.parallel = true
- Increasing the memory of gradle deamon to 3gb
- Updating to gradle 5
- Clearing all gradle caches
- Building without the gradle daemon
- Simplifying the build.gradle scripts. I have removed several plugins and tasks to rule them out as possible causes

I have only been using Gradle for a couple months now, so I am hoping to get feedback on more conclusive ways to find out what gradle is doing (or to find some way to cross it off the list of possible causes). Please let me know if any additional information would be helpful.

Comment: What I would try: disable the antivirus if you have one. Seriously.

Comment: @JB Nizet That is a good suggestion. We have some pretty annoying security software on all our machines. I am not even sure if I can disable it, but I will give it a try. Thanks, I will update with results.